# Error in assigning a value to an element in an array of struct

Tags: c++

I get this error in visual studio when running the code: **Unhandled exception at 0x0028457b in fileIO_experiment.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000018**

I am trying to allocate an array of structs inside one of my functions. The pointer to this array is declared in main, but passed on and used inside a function called getRow. The problem occurs when I try to assign a value to an element in the array of structs.

Here is my code :

In the main function:

```
int main()
{
.
.
.
DataRow* dataRowPointer = 0;
dataRowIndex = 0;

while ( myfile.good() )
{
        getRow( myfile, &loc, tcsPointer, dataRowPointer );
        globalLineCounter++;        
}
.
.
```

In the function getRow :

```
void getRow( std::istream& myfile, HeaderLocations* loc, TestCaseSet* tcsPointer, DataRow* dataRowPointer )
{
    std::string line;
    std::string word;    
    int currentLoc = 0;
    bool startStop = true;

    std::getline( myfile, line);        
    std::stringstream sline(line);

    while ( sline >> word )
    {
        if( word == "start" )
        {   
            dataRowIndex = -1;
            dataRowPointer = new DataRow[MAX_NUMBER_DATA_ROWS_PER_TEST_CASE_SET];              //Declaration of array of DataRow structs
            initializeDataRowPointer( dataRowPointer );          // Setting all values of previous array to default values

            testCaseSetID = captureTestCaseSetNumber( line, tcsPointer );
            getHeaderRow( myfile, loc );

            startStop = true;
            break;
        }
        else if ( word == "stop" )
        {   tcsNumber++;

            dataRowPointer = 0;
            startStop = true;
            break;
        }
        else
        {   startStop = false;  }
    }

    if( !startStop )
    {   dataRowIndex++;
        dataRowPointer[dataRowIndex].tcSetNum = testCaseSetID;      // <-- PROBLEM OCCCURS HERE
        getDataRow( line, loc, tcsPointer, dataRowPointer );    }
}
```

dataRowIndex is a global variable. This is only temporary until I fix this code.
I apologize in advance if my code is more C than C++, I am still a newbie.

Help would be much appreciated. Thank You!

Comment: I thought that would be done in the line : "dataRowPointer = new DataRow[MAX_NUMBER_DATA_ROWS_PER_TEST_CASE_SET]; "?

Comment: Only if you encounter "start" before you try assigning something to it. Run it through a debugger and follow the logic to the first point that an assignment is made one of it's data members. You will find that `dataRowPointer` does not contain a valid pointer value. Avoid using `0` and use `NULL` or `nullptr` instead.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very fragile piece of code.  If you have move than one "start", you leak and throw away memory.  You hit stop after start, you leak your pointer - heck you always leak your pointer.  You need to rethink how your create your memory for sure.

Your pointer is 0'd in stop, but you set a sentinel to catch that so it might be okay.

Here's the probable issue:
If all the words coming in are neither stop nor start (or your compares to strings don't work correctly) and `while(sline >> word)` eventually returns false as it is out of data or something, you never allocate memory and then attempt to read from it in your `!startStop` if statement.  This will cause a NULL exception.

Comment: The text file it reads from always has a row containing "start" before any row that would involve the !startStop if statement. When I run it through the debugger, it goes through the "dataRowPointer = new DataRow[MAX_NUMBER_DATA_ROWS_PER_TEST_CASE_SET];" first before going into if ( !startStop ) on the next iteration of the while loop. So I'm stuck on what's the problem

Comment: It's not probable, it is the cause. There's no guarantee that `dataRowPointer` points to a valid array of objects. Plus when it reaches "stop" it assigns a null pointer value to `dataRowPointer` which will also cause problems in the `!startstop` block.

Comment: Not to mention that there is no bounds check when incrementing `dataRowIndex` will likely cause UB.

Comment: Not to mention that "stop" causes a memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

dataRowPointer is a NULL pointer, the if statement is only entered if startStop is false. the only point in your code you initialize this pointer sets startStop to true and leaves the loop (break). it is not possible that you access a valid pointer inside your if.